# External JARs are not present in WAR

Tags: maven, jar, dependency-management

I have to use JAR's which don't exist on Maven repo.

I did that by creating libs folder where I put my JAR's and after that I went into pom.xml and did this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ABC</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/ABC.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

And this works, when I execute *mvn clean install* I can see these external JAR's in my "Maven Dependencies" list.

However after executing Maven command these JARs are not vissible in dependencies list on my *Application.war* which was created in target folder.

Do you know why this is happening? I'm failing to understand it and I didn't find solution so far.

Comment: Do not use system scope dependencies. Install the needed dependency in your repository manager and use it as a usual dependency...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) said, solution to my problem was adding my dependencies to my local Maven repository instead of using system scope and system path properties.

Guide for adding 3rd party JARs to your local Maven repository: https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying the same and found if i go via dependency then issue with NoClassDefFound error, So if you want to have external jar to be placed in .war\WEB-INF\lib\

you need to simply below steps:-

1.Create a “lib” folder under your project like this: “\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib”
2.Copy needed “jars” etc that you want included inside your WAR bundle folder.
3.Invoke your maven build as you normally do. I use “mvn install”, which creates builds the war file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).